# Getting logstash to write to a file and redis

Tags: linux, fail2ban

Ultimately, my goal here is to integrate my ShadowSOCKS server with fail2ban, but I'm having trouble with the intermediate step of getting the ShadowSOCKS container to write a log file (the ShadowSOCKS docker outputs its logs to stdout and lacks a syslog file). Since I already use an ELK stack to manage my containers and syslogs, I figured the easiest way to do this would be through logstash.

ShadowSOCKS, ELK, and fail2ban are all running in docker and are all functional except for this feature.

To write the file, I edited the logstash-agent config file as such:

```
input {
    gelf {
        port => 12201
    }
    file {
        path => "/var/log/syslog"
        start_position => "beginning"
        type => "syslog"
    }
}

output {
    redis {
        host => "redis-cache"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash"
    }

    if [tag] == "shadowsocks" {
        file {
            path => "/shadowsocks.log"
            codec => "json_lines"
        }
    }
}
```

I then share the file `/shadowsocks.log` with the host system via docker-compose:

```
...
  logstash-agent:
    image: logstash:7.11.1
    container_name: logstash-agent
    volumes:
      - ./logstash-agent:/etc/logstash
      - /var/log/syslog:/var/log/syslog:ro
      - /srv/shadowsocks/logs/shadowsocks.log:/shadowsocks.log
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 10.0.0.1:12201:12201/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
...
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but the log file isn't appearing.

Here's the shadowsocks container showing the gelf tag:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  shadowsocks:
    image: shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev
    container_name: shadowsocks
    ports:
      - 8388:8388
    environment:
      - METHOD=
      - PASSWORD=
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://10.0.0.1:12201"
        tag: "shadowsocks"
```

What am I missing here?